# Selenium Python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, pycharm

I am running following code in **PyCharm**

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox
```

Scripts executes successfully with following message in console

```
C:\Python34\python.exe C:/Users/dev/PycharmProjects/PYLearn/firs_selenium_script.py
```

> Process finished with exit code 0

But Firefox Browser is not opening, I have selenium installed using pip, Do I need additional setting to make this work.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

To launch the browser your code should look like:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://your-url')
```

After the test you will want the close the browser, so add:

```
self.browser.quit()
```

Hope this solve your problem.

More info: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

Go to Python Console at the bottom and run your commands and check the error

You can try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Browser should be opened , anyways check whether the browser started running or not.

Once, your browser fully loaded, your command will move to next line